# How to check if a discord embed contains specific keyword ? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to ping a specific role once a keyword matches the embed description.
However my bot does not detect the embeds i send as an embed.
I am using https://discohook.org/ for testing purposes. Every time i am sending an embed bot prints "NO EMBED FOUND" i have no idea whats wrong. Maybe someone can spot my mistake

```
import discord
import json

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
f = open("config.json")
config_data = json.load(f)
keywords = config_data["keywords"]
f.close()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Check if the message contains an embed
    if message.embeds:
        print("FOUND EMBED")
        # Get the first embed in the message
        embed = message.embeds[0]

        # Check if the embed description contains any of the keywords
        if any(keyword in str.lower(embed.description) for keyword in keywords):
            print("FOUND KW")
            # Get the role to tag
            role = message.guild.get_role(1049706948184002570)

            # Tag the role
            await message.channel.send(f"{role.mention}")
    else:
        print("NO EMBED FOUND")        

client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed your bot the `messages` intent?
This can prevent the bot from reading messages (except messages where the bot is mentioned).

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Note that you will also have to activate this option on the [developer page](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your bot.

Full code

```py
import discord
import json

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

f = open("config.json")
config_data = json.load(f)
keywords = config_data["keywords"]
f.close()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Check if the message contains an embed
    if message.embeds:
        print("FOUND EMBED")
        # Get the first embed in the message
        embed = message.embeds[0]

        # Check if the embed description contains any of the keywords
        if any(keyword in str.lower(embed.description) for keyword in keywords):
            print("FOUND KW")
            # Get the role to tag
            role = message.guild.get_role(1049706948184002570)

            # Tag the role
            await message.channel.send(f"{role.mention}")
    else:
        print("NO EMBED FOUND")        

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunatley still the same problem :(